# Squish Controller that Can Move up and down a Limb

Tags: animation, rigging

I have a rubber chicken character. Its neck is getting grabbed and stretched many times. What I would like to generate for this, is **a Squish controller that allows me to set where Squishing on the neck starts and where it ends**. Kind of like one of those two-way zippers that you can open and close towards the top and bottom. To see the principle in motion, this guy built a ribbon rig in blender 3 years ago.

Around 00:30 is what I am looking for.
https://vimeo.com/89682567

I have added a sketch of what that might work like.

[image: Squish Controls by Objects that influence a Displacement Gradient Ramp]

[image: Squish Control Prototype with position and scale via Vertex Weight Modifier and displacement]

My main idea is to use a gradient texture to displace a deform-cage that I have put around the neck. I have built a prototype that uses a Sphere object as a controller for a Vertex Weight Proximity Modifier. I then feed the modified Weights into a Displacement Modifier, whose influence is limited by them. This video shows what that looks like.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3n-hSFSi-SU

If any of you have an idea how to control Gradients through object positions or maybe just a simpler solution to the whole thing, I would greatly appreciate hearing it.

[image]

Comment: I think you want a [lattice deform](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+lattice+deform). A mesh deform is similar but using a custom mesh. You can also use an armature to deform the lattice which then deforms your chicken.

Comment: An object that controls a texture, that controls a modifier, that controls an object that deforms another object sounds like an unecessarily convoluted setup. You may be able to achieve the same result with a lighter simpler setup

Comment: I quite agree, and my hope was that somebody might provide that solution. ^__^